# Confirm Delete pop up with Record Count

Tags: javascript, asp.net, repeater

General Info:

Aspx page holds an Ascx User control. Inside the User control, the Repeater is contained inside a View, contained inside a Multiview.
Asp.Net 2.0 framework / C#

Details:

I have a repeater (inside an ascx user control) that shows records, and the first column is a checkbox. If checked, that row will be deleted.
OUtside the repeater, I have a button that will deleted all rows that are checked.

Everything works fine, but have been asked to add a pop up "confirm delete" message that includes the number of records that will be deleted if the user clicks "Ok" on the pop up.

Something like:
 "You are about to delete 8 records".

Currently my button looks like this:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteAllRecords" runat="server" Text="Delete all Checked Records" Onclick="btnDeleteAllRecords_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:GetCbCount();" />
```

I have this javascript code block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetCbCount()   
{
var cb = document.getElementById("rptrVoicemail").getElementsByTageName("input");
  var cbCount;   
for(i = 0;  i < cb.lenght; i++)   
{   
    if(cb[i].type == "checkbox")   
    {   
        if(cb[i].checked)   
        {   
            cbCount =  cbCount + 1;   
        }               
    }       
}
return confirm('You are about to delete' + cbCount + 'records.');

} 
</script>
```

When I click my button I'm getting:

Error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object
on this line:

```
var cb = document.getElementById("rptrVoicemail").getElementsByTageName("input");
```

Why is the JS not seeing my repeater? Is it because it's buried inside a MultiView? How can the JS be corrected so that the pop up will show the record count in the message?

**UPDATE**:
I changed the script to:

```
function GetCbCount(){ 
   var inpt = document.getElementById("vmDiv"); 
   var checkboxes = inpt.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
   var cbCount; 
   for(i = 0; i<checkboxes.lenght;i++){ 
      if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox" && checkboxes[i].checked){ 
         cbCount = cbCount + 1;
      } 
   } 
   return confirm('You are about to delete ' + cbCount + ' Voicemails.'); 
}
```

Comment: In the function the line begins with `var cb = ...` and in your error description with `var inpt = ...`. Is it an oversight?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for pointing that out. It's an oversight. I corrected my post.

Comment: Is your button next to the repeater? If so, you could use DOM-Model to get him. Another question: where is your Javascript located, inside the page or is it included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
document.getElementById('<%= rptrVoicemail.ClientID %>').getElementsByTageName("input");
```

Another approach is this little script that returns the ClientID. You could add it even to an included JS-file.

```
function GetClientId(strid)
{
     var count=document.forms[ 0 ].length ;
     var i = 0 ;
     var eleName;
     for (i = 0 ;  i < count ;  i++ )
     {
       eleName = document.forms [ 0 ].elements[ i ].id;
       pos=eleName.indexOf( strid ) ;
       if(pos >= 0)  break;          
     }
    return eleName;
 }
```

Found [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/889146.aspx).

Comment: Hi Tim, before trying your script, I made some changes to my origional script:   <script type="text/javascript">
function GetCbCount()   
{
    var cb = document.getElementById("vmDiv");
    var checkboxes = inpt.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var cbCount;   
    for(i = 0; i<checkboxes.lenght;i++)   
    {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox" && checkboxes[i].checked)   
        {        
            cbCount = cbCount + 1;                 
        }       
    }
 
  return confirm('You are about to delete ' + cbCount + ' Voicemails.');
 
}
</script>

Comment: It's working, but now will delete records no matter which button is clicked = OK or Cancel. Is my return statment not correct?

Comment: Another update: I changed my OnClientClick statment to: OnClientClick="if(GetCbCount() == false)return false;"   Now a 'Cancel' click stops the delte. New problem: The confirm pop up now shows "You are about to delete undefined records". "undefined" is supposed to be my record total.

Comment: I have updated your question with your current script(from the above comment). Yes, you must return GetCbCount() to delete only when user clicks OK. I would define cbCount in the following way: `var cbCount = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a master page or nesting controls (inside ascx, view, etc.) the framework will change the IDs that are rendered with elements.

If you do a "View Source" or use FireBug, you might see that `rptrVoicemail` became something like `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_someUserControl_ctl00_multiViewID_ctl28_rptrVoicemail`.

You can use `getElementById('<%= rptrVoicemail.ClientID %>')` to get at the ID of the element as it would be rendered on the client.

Edit: To help debug, do something like this... you get the point.

`var rptr = document.getElementById('<%= rptrVoicemail.ClientID %>');
rptr.borderColor = 'pink'; // draw a border to check it's the right element`

Comment: Thanks. Just did a ViewSource. Repeater is rendering as a plain html table. The table has id of 'tblRecords' as rendered in Viewsource.  Yes, am using Master Page. So the tree would be aspx page (with MasterPage), ascx user control, MultiView, View, Repeater.

Comment: repeater doesn't usually render anything - it's just a declarative replacement for a for-loop which will spit out whatever is defined in the HeaderTemplate, ItemTemplate, FooterTemplate.

Comment: Right. Since I've cretead an html table in the Repeater ItemTemplate, then it's spitting back a table.

Comment: Check that HeaderTemplate contains `<table id="tblRecords"...>`, footer contains `</table>` and ItemTemplate has rows as in `<tr>...</tr>`. Otherwise you'll end up with all the HTML tables with the same ID.

Comment: Hi Leon, I've got my table set up exactly as you've indicated. Other tables indeed have different id's.